# Handle bad JSON gracefully with Hash#fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash, error-handling

I'm trying to fetch some products from this JSON API so I can display them in my views, with bad JSON gracefully handled using `Hash#fetch` to declare a default value if I get nil.

But why am I getting:

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

or if I set `@json_text` to `{}`:

```
undefined method 'fetch' for `nil:NilClass`
```

Live app: http://runnable.com/U-QEWAnEtDZTdI_g/gracefully-handle-bad-json

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  require 'hashie'

  def index
    @json_text = <<END
{
    "products": []
}
END

    hashes = JSON.parse(@json_text)
    mashes = Hashie::Mash.new(hashes)

    products = []

    mashes.products.fetch('products', []).each do |mash|
      puts "YOLO"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For fetch, you need change the response to `response = JSON.parse(@json_text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to fetch is by calling `fetch` on mashes variable:

```rb
mashes.fetch('products', []).each do |mash|
  puts "YOLO"
end
```

[#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) is a Hash method and in this case is the same as mashes['product'], except when `product` is `nil`, using the `fetch` example will return `[]`

Comment: Thanks Thiago, but I can't seem to get the code inside that block working without `mashes.products`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213847/when-to-use-hashiemash

Comment: Can you add a json with the real structure you are having problems?

Comment: Hi. Please see `main_controller.rb` in http://runnable.com/U-QJCIFvY2RGWL9B/pretty-json-keys.

Comment: Ok, based on Hashie description and your example above, you probably want to do something like:

Comment: I answered on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213847/when-to-use-hashiemash/25215312#25215312

Comment: Very interesting - thanks a lot! But - 1) is there a way to remove `Hashie::Mash`?, 2) what if I am trying to parse multiple keys? Ie. `sale_price`, `name`, `currency` etc.?

Comment: You can see https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955 for the master file / structure (although it's using `Hashie::Mash`, and does not have a way to handle bad JSON gracefully).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58999/discussion-between-thiago-borges-and-mark-boulder).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215731/how-to-dry-up-method-with-multiple-not-found