# When to use Hashie::Mash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

Working on fetching some products from this JSON API and I was wondering -- do I really need `Hashie::Mash`?

Live app: http://runnable.com/U-QJCIFvY2RGWL9B/pretty-json-keys

`main_controller.rb`:

```
response = prettify(JSON.parse(@json_text))
mashie = Hashie::Mash.new(response)

@products = []
mashie.products.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  product.price = product.deep_fetch :sale_price

  @products << product
end
@products
```

I tried this:

```
response = prettify(JSON.parse(@json_text)['products'])

@products = []
response.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  product.price = product.deep_fetch :sale_price

  @products << product
end
@products
```

but that returns:

```
Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch::UndefinedPathError in MainController#index
Could not fetch path (sale_price) at sale_price
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
mashie.products.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  product.price = product.deep_fetch(:sale_price) { 'Not Found' }
  # Returns 'Not Found' if it does not find the key sale_price. It can be anything, like nil, 0, 'Not Found'

  @products << product
end
```

Comment: So in this sense I can remove `Hashie::Mash.new(response)`? Basically I'm just trying to simplify the code as much as possible. I'm not sure why I need `Hashie::Mash` in the first place (since I don't need to do `product.price?` etc.).

Comment: You can't because you need it to access the projects like `mashie.products`. Looks like this is a nice way to iterate over products on json.