# How to DRY up method with multiple { 'not found' }?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I'm trying to gracefully handle bad JSON for the following, where `Hash#fetch` doesn't seem to be an option ([Handle bad JSON gracefully with Hash#fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193627/handle-bad-json-gracefully-with-hashfetch/25214927)):

Live app: http://runnable.com/U-QJCIFvY2RGWL9B/pretty-json-keys (`main_controller.rb`)

So apparently the best way is to add `{ 'not found' }` to the end of each argument:

```
mashie.products.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  product.name = product.deep_fetch :name { 'not found' }
  product.brand = product.deep_fetch :brand, :name { 'not found' }
  product.price = product.deep_fetch :sale_price { 'not found' }
  product.currency = product.deep_fetch :currency { 'not found' }

  @products << product
end
```

**But is there a way to DRY this up?**

Edited: Updated as per discussion with @dax

Comment: product price always ends up as the value of deep_fetch :currency, doesn't it?

Comment: No, `:sale_price` and `:currency` are two different values.

Comment: @dax is refering to the fact that you're assigning to `product.price` three times, and wondering (as do I) if you meant to assign to different attributes instead.

Comment: Oops! That's a typo! Sorry about that, @dax, Amadan. Question edited.

Comment: @Amadan, that's right - Mark, I've added an answer that I think is a better fit given the updated information.

Comment: @dax there is oen problem, however: `deep_fetch` attributes will often consist of multiple keywords, ie. `product.deep_fetch :products, :images, 0, :size_name` -- how does one factor this into the equation?

Comment: Hmm, sorry i didn't understand that this was a possibility from the original question - neither answer handles that scenario, and without seeing a more specific example (ie, a hard-coded instance) I can't really say, although I suspect it would be much harder to pull off

Comment: Please see `main_controller.rb` at http://runnable.com/U-QJCIFvY2RGWL9B/pretty-json-keys for an example using `:brand, :name`.

Comment: Not too sure if we need to DRY up the `product.name =` part as `name` is a custom name reflecting whatever the author thinks is best for his or her views.

Comment: Let me know if this is one of those cases where DRYing up becomes too complicated for its own good :)

Comment: Too complicated. Ditching idea.

Comment: Mark, please use the '@' syntax for comments - then i'll get a notification and I can respond :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure about right syntax in `product.price = product.deep_fetch(attribute, { 'not found' })`:

```
mashie.products.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  i%[name sale_price currency].each do |attribute|
    product.price = product.deep_fetch attribute { 'not found' }
  end

  @products << product
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the clarification in the comments, I will also answer. My solution is much the same as Зелёный's, but it takes dynamic attribute setting into account

```
mashie.products.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  i%[name sale_price currency].each do |attribute|
    value = product.deep_fetch attribute { 'not found' }
    product.send("#{attribute}=", value)
  end

  @products << product
end
```