# Calling a setter method via a symbol

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, setter, getter

if `send` is used for calling a method with a symbol (which for an attribute is the getter method)

what is the opposite for accessing the setter method?

`object.send(:attr)`  is to `object.attr`

as

**______**  is to `object.attr = value`

sorry for the analogies, I don't know how to better explain this

Comment: `send` is for calling methods. It doesn't matter what the method does, `send` doesn't care. Can you clarify your question please? What makes you think that `send` can only be used to called some methods but not others?

Comment: the question was not on how send works, but how to access a setter via a symbol, see the answers below

Comment: Well, you just pass the name of the setter method. Like I said, `send` doesn't care what the method does, whether it sets something, gets something or prints pink unicorns on the screen, it simply calls it.

Comment: true, but I didn't care for `send` specifically, other alternatives were fine, I didn't know them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're trying to dynamically set the value of various attributes on an object.

try the following:

```
object.send("#{attr}=", value)
```

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215731/how-to-dry-up-method-with-multiple-not-found) asked yesterday - it might help as it's a more specific example.

Comment: it's probably not so difficult a situation if the value is going to be false.  you should ask a question about your specific problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
object.send(column + '=', column_value)
```

Comment: I guess `column` is `attr`?